# How to generalize Particle Filters (w.r.t. multiple states)

Tags: bayesian, hidden-markov-model, bayesian-network, particle-filter

I'm using particle filters for inference in a hidden markov model with an infinite state-space.
My current state-variable is multidimensional and there are interdependencies between some dimensions. I thought therefore, that it would be beneficial, if I split it up into sub-states and model ther dependences in a small bayesian network.

Thus, I would only maintain particles for each of the smaller-dimensional sub-states and hopefully get better results with fewer particles.
I thought, that representing N one-dimensional distributions needs fewer samples than representing the N-dimensional joint-distribution, represented by the Bayesian Network.

Does this make sense?

This leads to a Dynamic Bayesian Network, but I don't know how sampling, likelihood-weighting and resampling should be adapted for such a particle filter with multiple states.

**Update:**
Looks like `Nonparametric Belief Propagation` is an algorithm (class) that extends particle filtering techniques to arbitrarily structured graphical models.

Comment: When you are asking "does this make sense" are you asking if I understood what you already said, or are you asking if it is not technically problematic?  Does your "update" answer your own question?

Comment: The question of particle filtering arbitrary graphs is really interesting. I once found an excellent thesis which describes some solutions: [here](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~murphyk/Thesis/thesis.pdf)

Comment: "Variable Resolution Particle Filter" by Vandi Verma, Sebastian Thrun, and Reid Simmons seems to be related and might be of interest.  "http://robots.stanford.edu/papers/Verma03a.pdf"   However, it's not putting the PF into network form.